# How to calculate the sigma level between two normal distribution？

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, error-analysis, statistics

I often found the sigma level on paper of astronomy/cosmology.
For example,[This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-017-4827-4) said:

> Recently, the improved local measurement $H_{0} = 73.24 ±
> 1.74 km s^{−1} Mpc^{−1}$ from Riess et al. 2016 (hereafter R16)
>    exhibits a stronger tension with the Planck 2016 release
>   $H_{0} = 66.93±0.62 km s^{-1} Mpc^{−1}$ (hereafter P15)  at the
>   3.4σ level. ... The value of the Hubble constant $H_{0} = 68.34^{+0.53}_{ −0.92}$ is consistent with the P15’s result at the 1σ confidence level.

How do we figure 3.4σ and 1σ level out?

The other example , it is considered discovered once the excess reaches a 5 sigma level.It seems the bigger the sigma, the more the two data fit together.But for standard deviation, the smaller，the better,isn't it?

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.00055.pdf) also appeared σ.

Comment: Probably an error. $6\sigma$ is equivalent to $3.4 ppm$.

Comment: it' not 6σ，it's 3.4σ.

Comment: I am aware it is not written as $6\sigma$. I am suggesting that it might be a transcription error, because there is no particular significance to $3.4\sigma$ as far as I know. Elsewhere the article uses $1\sigma$. You suggested it might be related to $6\sigma$ (why?). I pointed out a coincidence which might explain where $3.4$ came from. To decide if it is an error, you could either (i) do the math,  or (ii) write to the corresponding author.

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, if you have $A \pm \delta A$ and $B \pm \delta B$, then $A-B$ an be determined (assuming the usual approximations of independent uncertainties that are normally distributed) with a precision of $\sqrt{(\delta A)^2 + (\delta B)^2)}$.

In this case, the difference in the two determinations of $H_0$ is $6.31 \pm 1.84$ km/s per Mpc. i.e. different from zero by 3.4 error bars. The $\sigma$ refers to the size of the uncertainty ; or more specifically, it represents the 68% confidence interval in a normal distribution.

Comment: How to figure the σ between $H_{0}=66.93±0.62 kms^{−1}Mpc^{−1}$ and $H0=68.34^{+0.53}_{−0.92}  kms^{−1}Mpc^{−1}$ ？

Comment: $\sqrt{0.92^2 + 0.62^2}=1.11$. The difference between the values is  1.41, so I do not agree that they are consistent within $1\sigma$. @HoisWang